# Simple--running shell script with a cronjob

Tags: linux, shell, linux-kernel, cron

Simple Question:

I want a cron job to run a script every minute. This script (script.sh) generates a .zip file of all the files in the directory. 
I have written the script in a file called script.sh:

```html
if [ -z "$(ls -A /var/www/html/convo_files)" ]; then
   exit
else
   zip -rj zipped.zip /var/www/html/convo_files/*
fi

Successfully creates .zip file when I run it with command ./script.sh
```

My crontab script is:

```html
*/1 * * * * /var/www/html/convo_files/script.sh
```

Gives message in mail (which looks correct):

```html
updating: crap.txt (deflated 89%)
updating: script.sh (deflated 36%)
```

Cronjob file is within same directory as script.sh btw, yet no .zip file is created with cronjob. Really not sure how to solve this dilemma.

Comment: "man crontab" will give you the answer.

Comment: What specifically in the manual?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried out the following cron job ?

```
*/1 * * * * /path/to/your/script.sh
```

This should execute your script every minute.

If you have problems executing the script make sure you have the "executable flag" set (chmod +x /path/to/your/script.sh)

If you still have errors you should take a look at your syslog. On most Linux systems the file `/var/log/syslog` is the currect one but this can differ from system to system.

Comment: I changed my script.sh file to

if [ -z "$(ls -A /var/www/html/convo_files)" ]; then
   exit
else
   zip -rj zipped.zip /var/www/html/convo_files/*
fi

And it gives the same message (in /var/spool/mail directory) as it does when I run it as ./script.sh. Yet, still no zip file created with cron command.

Comment: @user9965063 file zipped.zip will be created in your home directory; I just tested it and it works as expected.

Comment: I see! I want the zip file to be in the same directory  (/var/www/html/convo_files) however...

Answer (score 0):

Command in crontab file needed to be changed:

```html
* * * * * cd /var/www/html/convo_files && /var/www/html/convo_files/script.sh
```

Problem was working directory wasn't set right (https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/38951/what-is-the-working-directory-when-cron-executes-a-job )

For beginners like myself, make sure to look at your mail directory/log files to see your errors! 
Note, to go into your mail directory:

```html
cd /var/spool/mail
tail root
```

Thank you to everyone who answered and helped!